# Facebook API call crashing on iOS - Unity3D

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial and cannot figure out why this is crashing on iOS. No errors when played in the editor and untested on android. It crashes on this line `FB.API(url,Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,result =>` which is copied exactly as the tutorial says.

```
void FBOnLoggedIn(){             
        ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, FB.AccessTokenExpiresAt);
        currentUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser;

        // Reqest player info and profile picture                                                                           
        FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(500).fields(id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);  
        LoadPictureAPI(Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128), MyPictureCallback);

        currentUser["FacebookID"] = FB.UserId;

    }

void LoadPictureAPI (string url, LoadPictureCallback callback)
    {
        print ("load pic");
        FB.API(url,Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,result =>
               {
            if (result.Error != null)
            {
                Util.LogError(result.Error);
                return;
            }

            string imageUrl = Util.DeserializePictureURLString(result.Text);

            StartCoroutine(LoadPictureEnumerator(imageUrl,callback));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my Apple Dev Cert just expired a few minutes ago, I renewed it, and now no more crash. That is literally all I did, no change in code or anything. I can't imagine an almost expired cert would cause a crash when calling the FB API but apparently it does.